# A UI over Windows Workflow

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation

Are there any build in UI capabilities when using Windows Workflow..

Lets say I have a workflow that takes an hour to run where different activities are happening all the time. While it's running I want to see what activity is currently active, what activities have already ran etc..

Do I have to code this UI myself or does WF have built in features that graphically show the status etc of the workflow?

Answer (score 0):

To find out which state a workflow is in, I subscribe to the WorkflowIdled event and do something like this:

```
           private delegate void UpdateDelegate();
   void workflowRuntime_WorkflowIdled(object sender, WorkflowEventArgs e)
        {
            StateMachineWorkflowInstance stateMachineInstance = new StateMachineWorkflowInstance(MyManager.WorkflowRuntime, MyInstance.Id);
            UpdateDelegate LclUpdateDelgate = delegate()
            {
                // Update the workflow state on the form thread
                if (stateMachineInstance.CurrentState != null)
                    LabelWorkflowState.Text = stateMachineInstance.CurrentStateName;
                else
                    LabelWorkflowState.Text = "";

            };
            this.Invoke(LclUpdateDelgate);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in UI.

But you can create one, either by subscribing to events on the WorflowInstance (see other answer), or by using the [Tracking Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms735887.aspx).

The former is simple to set up for a quick solution but the latter will work with multiple host processes and long running (unloaded) workflow instances.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the this code sample over at MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741706.aspx